# C# WPF user control not disposing when parent window is closed

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a main window we'll call `main` and a child window we'll call `child` with a user control in the `child` we'll call `control`.

Program starts with `main` and the user performs some action to launch `child` which has `control` which has a `FileSystemWatcher` among other things. However, I started noticing that the `FileSystemWatcher` events are still firing after `child` has been closed.  *Uh oh.*  So I start digging...

When I subscribe to the `Window_Closing` event for `child` it triggers as expected.  When I subscribe to the `UserControl_Unloaded` event for `control` it triggers as expected (immediately after `child` closes).  So I put a destructor on `control`, which apparently is not happening until `main` is closed.

*So why is the destructor for my user control not disposing the properties when the user control is unloaded?*  I would include code snippets if I knew which ones were pertinent...

Comment: How and where exactly are you disposing that `FileSystemWatcher`? Are you setting a field to `null`, or are you properly calling `Dispose` on it?

Comment: @Pieter I'm just setting it to null when the UserControl_Unloaded event triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after typing the question, the awesomeness of StackOverflow showed me [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222400/wpf-user-control-not-being-disposed) which had a decent generic answer.

My solution was to unsubscribe all the `FileSystemWatcher` events in the `UserControl_Unloaded` event.  Simply setting the watcher object to null was not sufficient.  Seems like that's too much work for a managed language like .NET, but I guess not.

Comment: It will use underlying file system objects to achieve this.  Not everything is managed.  Rule of thumb for me, if any object you create implements the IDisposable - dispose of it appropriately depending on the scope its used.

Comment: @Andez I'll have to pay more attention to IDisposable inheritance from now on.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`FileSystemWatcher` implements `IDisposable`. That normally indicates that a class uses unmanaged resources (such as file handles or unmanaged memory) that cannot be automatically (or timely) reclaimed by the garbage collector. `IDisposable` offers a `Dispose` method that such classes can use to properly release their unmanaged resources. Of course, cleanup could be done by other methods as well, but the `IDisposable` 'convention' makes it much easier for programmers to see which classes need cleanup. This also means that the word 'dispose' has a very specific meaning in C#.

It looks like a `FileSystemWatcher` remains alive if it's not disposed. Because you didn't remove those event handlers, it still contains references to your user control, so that remains alive as well, and you continue to see events being raised. Removing event handlers is a good idea (especially when the event-raising object has a longer lifespan), but in this case it only solves the symptom, not the underlying problem: it allows your user control to be reclaimed by the garbage collector, but the `FileSystemWatcher` is still alive.

As for destructors (they're normally called finalizers in C#), those are rarely needed. They can be used as a last resort by classes that implement `IDisposable` - just in case a programmer forgot to call `Dispose` - but there's a little cost to them (finalizers need to be registered in a queue and they're called by a special finalizer thread) and you can't control when exactly they are executed.